# Overwrite sheet if it exists

Tags: vba, excel

I recorded a macro that makes some pivot tables in a new sheet and it works fine, so i tried to make it able to overwrite if the sheet already existed but i can't seem to make it work. The problem is that when i use the macro once it does add the new sheet but it also adds another one on top of the one already made, and when i try to use the macro again to see if it overwrites the other one, it doesn't it just adds another unnamed sheet.
The code looks like this:

```
Sub Makro7()

Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
On Error Resume Next
Sheets.Add().Name = "Statistics"
On Error GoTo 0

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Base!R1C1:R18288C12", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    "Statistics!R1C1", TableName:="Pivottabel22", DefaultVersion:=6
Sheets("Statistics").Select
Cells(1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabel22").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "Pivottabel22").PivotFields("FACULTY_ID"), "Antal af FACULTY_ID", xlCount
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabel22").PivotFields("FACULTY_ID")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabel22").PivotFields("PROGRAM_TYPE_NAME")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabel22").DataPivotField.PivotItems( _
    "Antal af FACULTY_ID").Caption = "Antal"
Range("B1").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabel22").CompactLayoutColumnHeader = "Fakultet"
Range("A7").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Statistics").PivotTables("Pivottabel22").PivotCache. _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Statistics!R7C1", TableName:= _
    "Pivottabel23", DefaultVersion:=6
Sheets("Statistics").Select
Cells(7, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabel23").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "Pivottabel23").PivotFields("FACULTY_ID"), "Antal af FACULTY_ID", xlCount
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabel23").PivotFields("PROGRAM_TYPE_NAME")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabel23").PivotFields("FACULTY_ID")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabel23").PivotFields("Antal af FACULTY_ID")
    .Calculation = xlPercentOfTotal
    .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
End With
Range("A7").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabel23").DataPivotField.PivotItems( _
    "Antal af FACULTY_ID").Caption = "Procentvis"
Range("B7").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabel23").CompactLayoutColumnHeader = "Fakultet"
Range("A13").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Statistics").PivotTables("Pivottabel23").PivotCache. _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Statistics!R13C1", TableName:= _
    "Pivottabel24", DefaultVersion:=6
Sheets("Statistics").Select
Cells(13, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabel24").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "Pivottabel24").PivotFields("ENROLL_LOCATION_NAME"), _
    "Antal af ENROLL_LOCATION_NAME", xlCount
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabel24").PivotFields("ENROLL_LOCATION_NAME" _
    )
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
Range("B13").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabel24").DataPivotField.PivotItems( _
    "Antal af ENROLL_LOCATION_NAME").Caption = "Antal"
Range("A13").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabel24").CompactLayoutRowHeader = "Campus"
Range("B13").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabel24").DataPivotField.PivotItems("Antal"). _
    Caption = "Antal af studerende"
Range("A22").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Statistics").PivotTables("Pivottabel24").PivotCache. _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Statistics!R22C1", TableName:= _
    "Pivottabel25", DefaultVersion:=6
Sheets("Statistics").Select
Cells(22, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabel25").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "Pivottabel25").PivotFields("ENROLL_LOCATION_NAME"), _
    "Antal af ENROLL_LOCATION_NAME", xlCount
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabel25").PivotFields("ENROLL_LOCATION_NAME" _
    )
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabel25").PivotFields( _
    "Antal af ENROLL_LOCATION_NAME")
    .Calculation = xlPercentOfTotal
    .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
End With
Range("A22").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabel25").CompactLayoutRowHeader = "Campus"
Range("B22").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabel25").DataPivotField.PivotItems( _
    "Antal af ENROLL_LOCATION_NAME").Caption = "Procentvis af studerende"
Range("I1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Statistics").PivotTables("Pivottabel25").PivotCache. _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Statistics!R1C9", TableName:= _
    "Pivottabel26", DefaultVersion:=6
Sheets("Statistics").Select
Cells(1, 9).Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabel26").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "Pivottabel26").PivotFields("STUDYBOARD_ID"), "Antal af STUDYBOARD_ID", xlCount
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabel26").PivotFields("STUDYBOARD_ID")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
Range("I1").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabel26").CompactLayoutRowHeader = "Studienævn"
Range("J1").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivottabel26").DataPivotField.PivotItems( _
    "Antal af STUDYBOARD_ID").Caption = "Antal af studerende"
Range("L15").Select
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this piece of code:

```
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
On Error Resume Next
Sheets.Add().Name = "Statistics"
On Error GoTo 0
```

This basically tells Excel to add a new sheet after the active sheet and when you run the macro the second time, the sheetname "Statistics" is already taken. (And if it wasn't for `On error resume next`, an error message would appear the second time). Add this at the top of your macro instead:

```
Dim newSheet As Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set newSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)
With newSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Statistics").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    .name = "Statistics"
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: It works but the problem now is that it only works if there already is a sheet called Statistics. It says that subscript is out of range if i don't already have sheet called Statistics

Comment: @yomomo. Fixed it.